# firewalld allowing traffic to docker container. Why is it so?

Tags: docker, centos, firewalld

I am trying to get the firewalld concepts *right*. Installed docker and firewalld on Rocky Linux 9.0. My ngnix container is UP and running on port 8089. Without **http** services in any of the firewalld zones, how does traffic hit my nginx server? My default zones are **public** & **docker**.

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0 eth1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=docker --list-all
docker (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker0
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Access to containerized services is controlled via rules in the `FORWARD` chain, not in the `INPUT` chain. You would need to add rules that permit (or prohibit) specific forwarded connections. Generally, you add these rules to the `DOCKER-USER` chain. I'm not familiar with firewalld so I can't offer specific syntax suggestions.